# combining multiple LInq selector expressions into a single expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression, selector

I'm targetting an API that takes a parameter defined as follows

```
Select(Expression<Func<User, object>> selectExpression);
```

The expression is used to select one or multiple properties, e.g. like this

```
var expr = (u) => new { u.FirstName, u.LastName};
```

I'd like to write this selectExpression dynamically, where I'm able to submit list of property name. So something along these lines

```
private static Expression<Func<User, object>> generateSelectExpression(List<string> propertiesToSelect)
```

Not that this is not about EntityFramework or any other DB layer, it's pure object magic.

Comment: Taking a closer look, I don't think there is an easy way to do this. The big problem here is that you want to return an _anonymous_ type. Normally the compiler would generate this type for you, but you want to define the type at runtime, and this cannot be done with an expression.

Comment: @RenéVogt I think the fact that it returns an anonymous type is the only reason this works.

Comment: In this case you are better off with a dictionary rather than a dynamic anonymous type. Will serve the purpose more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

It takes some dynamic/reflection magic, but this should do it

Edited to allow for generics, not just User class

```
    static void Sample()
    {
        List<string> properties = new List<string>();
        properties.Add("FirstName");
        properties.Add("LastName");

        var exp = generateSelectExpression<User>(properties);
    }

    class User
    {
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, object>> generateSelectExpression<T>(List<string> propertiesToSelect)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, object>> exp = (x) => GetDynamicFromDictionary(GetProperties(x), propertiesToSelect);
        return exp;
    }

    private static dynamic GetDynamicFromDictionary(Dictionary<string,object> dict, List<string> propertiesToSelect)
    {
        var eo = new ExpandoObject();
        var eoColl = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)eo;

        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            if (propertiesToSelect.Contains(kvp.Key))
            {
                eoColl.Add(kvp);
            }
        }

        dynamic eoDynamic = eo;

        return eoDynamic;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, object> GetProperties(object obj)
    {
        var props = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (obj == null)
            return props;

        var type = obj.GetType();
        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var val = prop.GetValue(obj, new object[] { });
            props.Add(prop.Name, val);
        }

        return props;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that only seems to be half of the story. I'm adding that func to the GraphServiceClient (Microsoft.Graph nuget package)'s graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Select() command and it bombs out with this error:

Unrecognized lambda expression.\r\nParameter name: selectExpression

If I build the expression as in my second code bit, it passes just fine. So it seems the MS Graph lib cannot resolve more complex expressions.